# Custom Type dilemma with any and unknown

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on the following code to generate a bar chart from an external `json` source.

All was fine until I added:

`d3.json('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5eee6a5397cb753b4d149343').then(data => this.drawBars(data))`

which resulted in:

`Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'` error.

After researching it, I realized that I had to create a custom type for `data` to avoid the unknown inference.

So, I added `DataType` instead of the previous `any[]` for the `drawBars` method's parameter type.

However, I get this error:

`Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DataType[]'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'DataType[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

What am I doing wrong here?

**This is the code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

type DataType = {
    Framework: string;
    Stars: number;
    Released: number;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar',
  templateUrl: './bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar.component.css']
})
export class BarComponent implements OnInit {

  // Hardcoded data needed to generate the chart. Here, it is the
  // number of stars each popular front-end web development framework has!
  data = [
    {"Framework": "Vue", "Stars": "166443", "Released": "2014"},
    {"Framework": "React", "Stars": "150793", "Released": "2013"},
    {"Framework": "Angular", "Stars": "62342", "Released": "2016"},
    {"Framework": "Backbone", "Stars": "27647", "Released": "2010"},
    {"Framework": "Ember", "Stars": "21471", "Released": "2011"},
  ];

  // Property used to store the SVG image that D3 draws onto the DOM.
  svg: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, HTMLElement, any>;

  // Properties used to set the margin, height and width for the chart.
  margin = 50;
  width = 750 - (this.margin * 2);
  height = 400 - (this.margin * 2);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();   
    // Fetch data from an external endpoint; e.g. a JSON API endpoint or file.
    d3.json('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5eee6a5397cb753b4d149343').then(data => this.drawBars(data));
  }

  createSvg(): void {
    this.svg = d3.select("figure#bar")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width + (this.margin * 2))
    .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 2))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + "," + this.margin + ")");
  }

  drawBars(data: any[]): void {
    // Create the X-axis band scale.
    const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, this.width])
    .domain(data.map(d => d.Framework))
    .padding(0.2);

    // Draw the X-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

    // Create the Y-axis band scale.
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 200000])
    .range([this.height, 0]);

    // Draw the Y-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Create and fill the bars.
    this.svg.selectAll("bars")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", d => x(d.Framework))
    .attr("y", d => y(d.Stars))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d) => this.height - y(d.Stars))
    .attr("fill", "#d04a35");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in stackblitz

Comment: Do you see the problem with my code? Any idea what I am missing or how I should declare my custom type for `data`?

Comment: use `then((data:any[]) => this.drawBars(data))` to say typeScript that the data is an array

Comment: @Eliseo THANK YOU! It works :-) Please put your comment as an answer, so I mark it as accepted answer. Cheers